# Google Chrome issue with jquery page scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have set up one page scrolling animation on a website built using Wordpress.

The site can be viewed here - http://nutricalm.co.za/

This is the scripting I used to achieve the animated scroll to the desired destination which is determined by clicking on an anchor link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Get the height of the header
var headerHeight = $("div#header").height() + 45;

// Attach the click event
$('a[href*=#]').bind("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var target = $(this).attr("href"); //Get the target
var scrollToPosition = $(target).offset().top - headerHeight;

$('html').animate({ 'scrollTop': scrollToPosition }, 600, function(){
    window.location.hash = "" + target;
    // This hash change will jump the page to the top of the div with the same id
    // so we need to force the page to back to the end of the animation
    $('html').animate({ 'scrollTop': scrollToPosition }, 0);
});


});

</script>

<div id="menu-smallest" role="navigation">
<select id="mobi-menu" >
  <option value="#slider">HOME</option>
  <option value="#about">ABOUT</option>
  <option value="#nutricalm">GE NUTRICALM</option>
  <option value="#indications">INDICATIONS</option>
  <option value="#barrier">BARRIER SHAMPOO</option>  
  <option value="#contact">CONTACT</option>
</select>
```

The problem is the page scrolling animation works on all browsers I have tested except on Chrome where it only jumps to the anchor clicked on as it would without the jquery animation. I am assuming this is a webkit issue. Any ideas how to fix this?